# Android Compose: how to get notification permission

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-notifications, android-permissions, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I need to get permission to turn do not disturb mode on or off. Normally, without composing I would use the following code and check the result of the launched activity:

```
val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (!mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
        val intentNotifica = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
        startActivity(intentNotifica)
    }
```

But with jetpack compose I would not know how to check if the user has obtained the permissions or not. For example, with the following code, I cannot know, after the user has pressed the button, if the permissions have been obtained or not:

```
fun DoNotDisturbPermission() {

val context = LocalContext.current
val hasPermission = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

if (!hasPermission.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
    Button(onClick = {
        val intentNotifica = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
        context.startActivity(intentNotifica)
    }) {
        Text("get permission")
    }
} else {
    Text("Already granted")
}}
```

Also, I tried to use the Accompanist library with `rememberPermissionState(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)`, but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it. I have the files below in a Permissions package in my Utils package.

Permission Checker:

```
   @Composable
    fun checkNotificationPolicyAccess(
        notificationManager: NotificationManager,
        context: Context
    ): Boolean {
        if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
            return true
        } else {
            PermissionDialog(context)
        }
        return false
    }
```

Permission Dialog:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun PermissionDialog(context: Context) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            properties = DialogProperties(
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = true
            ),
            title = { Text("Permission Needed") },
            text = {
                Text("Allow ******* to access Do Not Disturb Settings? Pressing 'No' will close the app as it cannot work without access. Thanks.")
            },
            onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = true },

            dismissButton = {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        exitProcess(0)
                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFF9800))
                ) {
                    Text(text = "No")
                }
            },
            confirmButton = {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
                        startActivity(context, intent, null)

                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xffFF9800))
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Yes")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then my main activity looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {   
                    checkNotificationPolicyAccess(notificationManager, this)
                    HomePage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the problem remains: if the user presses on "yes" and subsequently does not get permission (for example by pressing the back key), then the dialog is no longer shown until the process is closed and reopened ( or in any case there is no way to verify if the user has actually obtained the permissions).

Comment: You just need to do ```checkNotificationPolicyAccess``` again before your next event, no?